# Merge data frames with missing values by its coordinate

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have a very simple problem but I can't figure it out. I've been trying for hours and previous read [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871916/merging-data-frames-with-missing-values-in-r) answers but none of them addresses directly my problem.
I have to append columns to a dataframe dynamically. 
Let's say I have:

```
df1 <- data.frame (c("a","b","c","d"))
df2 <- data.frame (c("aa", "bb", "ccc"))
df3 <- data.frame (c("aaa", "bbb"))
df4 <- data.frame (c("aaaa"))
df5 <- data.frame ()
```

Notice that none them has a the same number of rows, nor have primary keys values. And one them is empty. 
How can I merge these 5 dataframes by their coordinates in one dataframe `df6`, filling the missing values with `N/A`?

To be more specific, I want the final output to be like: `df6`

```
a   aa  aaa aaaa N/A
b   bb  bbb N/A  N/A
c   cc  N/A N/A  N/A
d   N/A N/A N/A  N/A
```

Comment: What is the expected output when `df3 <- data.frame (c("aaa", "ccc"))` ?

Comment: I have written the expected output in the question. which is df6

Comment: Read above comment again please. Do you want to line up the letters? As on 1st row, Bs on 2nd row, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cbind.fill` function from `rowr` package with `fill` option as `NA`

```
library(rowr)
cbind.fill(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, fill = NA)


1    a  aa    aaa  aaaa   NA
2    b  bb    bbb  <NA>   NA
3    c  ccc  <NA>  <NA>   NA
4    d  <NA> <NA>  <NA>   NA
```